# how to modify pointers with a void function in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

So im trying to build a function to search in a BST a value given by the user (int key) and i came up with the function below. basically what it does, or it should do, is search the key, if it finds it it should modify the "found" pointer and pass the node where the key is to it, then should find the predecessor and successor of the key and pass them to pre and suc.

this is the function

```
void findPreSuc(struct node *root, struct node* found, struct node* pre, struct node* suc, int key)
{
    // Base case
    if (root == NULL){  
        return ;
    }
    // If key is present at root
    if (root->data == key)
    {
        found=root;
        printf("\n%d",found->data); //test if root node gets passed to found
        // the maximum value in left subtree is predecessor
        if (root->left_child != NULL)
        {
            struct node* tmp = root->left_child;
            while (tmp->right_child){
                tmp = tmp->right_child;
                pre = tmp ;
            }
        }
 
        // the minimum value in right subtree is successor
        if (root->right_child != NULL)
        {
            struct node* tmp = root->right_child;
            while (tmp->left_child){
                tmp = tmp->left_child;
                suc = tmp ;
            }
        }
        return ;
    }
 
    // If key is smaller than root's key, go to left subtree
    if (root->data > key)
    {
        suc = root ;
        findPreSuc(root->left_child, found, pre, suc, key) ;
    }
    else // go to right subtree
    {
        pre = root ;
        findPreSuc(root->right_child, found, pre, suc, key) ;
    }
}
```

when i run the inputs below

```
int main()
{
    struct node *root=NULL;
    struct node *suc=NULL;
    struct node* pre=NULL;  
    struct node* found=NULL;
    root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);
    findPreSuc(root, found, pre, suc, 60);
    if (found==NULL)
    {
        printf("\ndidnt work");
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

i get this output

```
60
didnt work
```

it means the function gets executed with no errors and during its execution the 3 pointers found, pre and suc do actually get modified (the code prints 60 from the found->data) but when the function ends the pointers get set back to NULL and i get the "didnt work" print
any advice?

Comment: Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: You're modifying a pointer parameter that was passed by value, so a copy of the original. You need a double pointer if you want to be able to modify what the original points to inside the function.

Comment: Or, `return` the updated pointer value for the caller to assign to their pointer.

Comment: It would probably make sense for `findPreSuc` to return a pointer to the found node, or `NULL` if not found. Then you would not need the `found` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To modify any pointer passed to the function you need to pass **pointer to pointer**.

Example:

```
void foo(char **x)
{
    *x = "foo";
}

int main(void)
{
    char *bar = "bar";
    
    printf("bar is: '%s'. Calling the function `foo` ... \n", bar);
    foo(&bar);
    printf("Now bar is: '%s'\n", bar);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MW9caaMWz

Comment: okay so a solution should be passing to the function called in the main the addresses of the pointers i have created via & like this for example "findPreSuc(root, &found, &pre, &suc, 60);" and then in the function itself when i pass stuff like "pre=root" or "found=root" i have to pass it like "*found=root" or "*pre=root", is it right?

Comment: if you want to modify pointer passed to the function you need to pass a reference to it. I am not going to read your examples - you have all needed information in my ansdwer